# A weird symbol related to Sobolev spaces on manifolds

Tags: fonts, symbols, math-fonts

Can someone tell me what the following mathematical symbol is?

[image]

I don't know the symbol to the left of the indices p and k. Here is a snapshot of my textbook that is related to this symbol:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The symbol you are looking for is **MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR CAPITAL E** (U+1D508):  (followed by p over k, but that's not the issue, I understand.)

Quick MWE, showing two ways:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\mathfont}{NotoSansMath}

\begin{document}

$\mathfrak{E}$ vs. {\mathfont\symbol{"1D508}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was finally able to reproduce the symbol with the syntax $\mathfrak{E}$, despite a slight variation of the one shown in my book.

Comment: That, or you simply use a font that supports the corresponding Unicode glyph. Either way, glad it's working four you.